# Why is my derived class not converible to base class?

Tags: c#, radix, derived

I have the following classes:

```
public class Item
{
}

public class ItemCollection<TItem> : ICollection<TItem> where TItem : Item, new()
{
}
```

I have two derived classes:

```
public class Feature : Item
{
}

public class Features : ItemCollection<Feature>
{
}
```

I have a manager class to manage such collections:

```
public class ItemCollectionManager<TCollection> where TCollection : ItemCollection<Item>, new()
{
}
```

I tried to use this class:

```
public class FeatureManager : ItemCollectionManager<Features>
{
}
```

but this results in:

"The type `Features` must be convertible to `ItemCollection<Item>` in order to use it as TCollection in the generic class `ItemCollectionManager<TCollection>`".

And as previously mentioned,

`Features` is-a `ItemCollection<Feature>`

and

`Feature` is-a `Item`.

I do not believe interfaces are the ideal solution to this task but am willing to change if reason is provided.

If anyone could advise on what I'm doing wrong it would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do the...

```
ItemCollection<Feature> features = ...;
ItemCollection<Item> items = features;
```

It's about generics `variance` (covariance and contravariance that is) - **and it's only supported for interfaces, delegates - and only providing they're designed that way** (decorated with `in` / `out` - and conforming to the rules that go with it). e.g. `IEnumerable<>` is (if you lookup its definition you'll see the `out`). For more details I think it's best to read more...

[How is Generic Covariance & Contra-variance Implemented in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-sharp-4-0/246101#246101)
[Understanding Covariant and Contravariant interfaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719954/understanding-covariant-and-contravariant-interfaces-in-c-sharp/2720046#2720046)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

In your case, you could design an `IItemCollection<out T>` (`interface`) - that (**theoretically**) might support the casting you need. But it'd have to be `read-only` (*a tad simplified and not entirely correct but it's easier to think that way - the rules are a bit more complex*).

Since you're naming it a 'collection' I'm assuming it's not just for enumerating, viewing the items - i.e. if you have an `Add` of a sort (which requires `input parameters` - i.e. `contra-variance`) that clashes with the 'covariance' you need for the `upcasting`. Also any other parameters involved might not allow your interface to be made covariant.

---

Also some other posts I made related...

[How to make generic class that contains a Set of only its own type or subtypes as Children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590540/how-to-make-generic-class-that-contains-a-set-of-only-its-own-type-or-subtypes-a/15599634#15599634)

[C# generic handlers, what am I misunderstanding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723317/c-sharp-generic-handlers-what-am-i-misunderstanding/15723829#15723829)

Comment: +1 for covariance and links.  And I had no idea you could decorate type arguments with in / out.

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare you're welcome - yes, it could be useful in certain scenarios

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional generic argument on ItemCollectionManager, TItem.

I believe your ItemCollectionManager class definition should look something like this.

```
    public class ItemCollectionManager<TCollection, TItem> where TCollection : ItemCollection<TItem>, new(), 
where TItem : Item
    {
    }
```

The way you have the `FeatureManager` class defined right now it would be entirely acceptable to add ANY CLASS which inherits `Item` to the `TCollection`, since the only restriction on `TCollection` is that it contains classes of type `Item`.  The collection `Features` accepts only `Feature` classes or classes which inherit the `Feature` type.  Since you can't add the base type of `Item` to `Features`, it should not compile.

Comment: Implementing it that way creates further issues down the line, and I didn't believe supplying TItem was necessary since it's just going to be an `Item` anyway. But if this is required please could you explain a little more about why?

Comment: I've added some explanation.  If it still isn't clear then let me know and i'll try and explain it better.